# Can I say 真看起来?

Tags: grammar

I want to say:

Rome really does look like it was built in a day.

It is a joke of course.

罗马真看起来是一天建成的

Would this be correct ?

Comment: It is better to add a 地 or 的 like 真地看起来 or 真的看起来. However, we prefer 看起来真地 or 看起来真的.

Comment: So would you say 罗马真的看起来是一天建成的 or 罗马看起来真的是一天建成的 ？

Comment: Yes, we usually use 罗马看起来真的是一天建成的.

Comment: @hinen Great , finally can I say “罗马不是一天建成的，然而，罗马看起来真的是一天建成的” ?

Comment: The subjects are the same so the second one can be dropped. 虽然罗马不是一天建成的，然而看起来真的是一天建成的。

Comment: @hinen But can I drop the first 虽然 ？  I know it works with the structure 虽然A然而B but I’d like to start with the original phrase 罗马不是一天建成的

Comment: Yes, you can drop it.

Comment: does this joke make sense? I don't get it...sorry. Tried to think of a similar expression in Chinese but couldn't for now..

Comment: @sylvia It’s a joke where a picture is shown of various ruins in Rome and the text is “Rome wasn’t built in a day, it just looks that way.” The joke is obviously implying that nothing was completed.

Answer (score 1):

Try 看来罗马'**真**'不是一天建成的.

To add more effect, you can put an emphasis on 真 while you speak.

Answer (score 1):

Well, they say:

Rome wasn't built in a day.
一口吃不成胖子。

The contradiction of that might be:

我只一口吃就成胖子！

Rome really looks like it was built in a day!
看起来罗马就是在一天内建成的！

Buon Natale!